# Property of infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I am looking at the first proof shown here
http://mathaa.epfl.ch/cours/PMMI2001/interactive/negbinomexpect_en0.htm
and I am a bit lost on how
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {j + r \choose r} (1-p)^j = p^{-r-1}, \quad 0 < p < 1.
\end{equation}
Could anyone explain this to me? If the choose function were not in the sum, then I see it as a geometric series, but I am not sure what to think of the choose function.

Comment: Which of the shows did not make sense?

Comment: Going from show 3 to 4 in the first proof, explicitly the equivalence I noted above. I change the notation of $C_{j + r}^r$ to ${j + r \choose r}$.

Comment: just change $1-p=x$ and use Taylor's serious for $(1-x)^{-1-r}.$

Comment: Do you know how to apply the negative binomial theorem to $(1 - (1-p) )^{-r-1}$

Comment: @AlexMardikian See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalisations) for the expansion. Your coefficient is slightly off.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, I see the equivalence in the Wikipedia page. Is this what you meant by the negative binomial theorem in the comment before the wiki link?
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^s}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{s+k-1\choose k}x^k\equiv\sum_{k=0}^\infty{s+k-1\choose s-1}x^k
\end{equation}
I never saw this before for $(x+y)^r$ where $r<0$ until now.

Comment: It can also be shown that $$\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k {n+k-1 \choose k} x^k = 1/(1+x)^n$$ by induction on $n$ (using Pascal's rule). Your result follows by setting $x=p-1, r=n-1$.

Comment: (At the step $n+1$, the left hand side is a sum over $k \geq 0$ which I denote by $S$, and Pascal's rule, as well as the induction hypothesis, allows you to write $$S = 1/(1+x)^n  -  x \cdot S,$$ whence $S = 1/(1+x)^{n+1}$ as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural probabilistic proof. Suppose we are tossing a coin repeatedly. Let the probability of success (heads) be $p$. For a fixed $r$, let $X$ be the number of **failures** until the $(r+1)$-th success.

We find an expression for the probability that $X=j$.

Let $j=0$. The probability of $0$ failures until the $(r+1)$-th success is simply $p^{r+1}$. But to make it look nice, we call it $\binom{0+r}{r}p^{r+1}$. Thus
$$\Pr(X=0)=\binom{0+r}{r}p^{r+1}.$$

Let $j=1$. We find the probability of $1$ failure until the $(r+1)$-th success. So in the first $1+r$ trials, we must have had $r$ successes exactly, so $1$ failure, and then success on the $(r+2)$-th trial.

The probability of $r$ successes (and therefore $1$ failure) in $r+1$ trials is 
$\binom{1+r}{r}p^r(1-p)^1$. The probability that this is followed by success is $p$. We conclude that
$$\Pr(X=1)=\binom{1+r}{r}p^{r+1}(1-p)^1.$$

The probability of $r$ successes (and therefore $2$ failures) in $r+2$ trials is 
$\binom{2+r}{r}p^r(1-p)^2$. The probability that this is followed by success is $p$. We conclude that
$$\Pr(X=2)=\binom{2+r}{r}p^{r+1}(1-p)^2.$$

The same argument shows that for any $j\ge 0$, 
$$\Pr(X=j)=\binom{j+r}{r}p^{r+1}(1-p)^j.\tag{A}$$

With probability $1$, we will get to our $(r+1)$-th success at sometime or other. So the sum of the $\Pr(X=j)$ must be equal to $1$. It follows from (A) that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\Pr(X=j)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+r}{r}p^{r+1}(1-p)^j=1.\tag{B}$$

Divide by $p^{r+1}$ to get the formula you asked for a proof of.